# HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest and "ContentType" page directive

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the `HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest` method to render ASPX pages outside of IIS, which all works fine when my ASPX pages render HTML.

However, I also have ASPX pages that render XML and therefore set the `ContentType` Page directive to `text/xml`.  The problem is that the `ProcessRequest` method only returns a string that represents the content and therefore doesn't have a way to set the ContentType in the Response to the value indicated in the Page directive.

How can I get the `ContentType` value in from the Page directive into the `ContentType` value in the `Response`?

Comment: Could you do it using [SendKnownResponseHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.sendknownresponseheader.aspx) and passing it a [HeaderContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.headercontenttype.aspx) or have you tried that already?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in your implementation of HttpWorkerRequest.  Most people use SimpleWorkerRequest (provided by the framework), but the fact is that it only works for "Simple" requests.  You likely need a more complete implementation of HttpWorkerRequest.

The Cassini project has an implementation that you can probably use that will likely solve your problem.